# Composer autoload, class not found

Tags: php, composer-php

I get this error: Fatal error: Class 'Handlers\AuthenticateHandler' not found

My composer.json

```
    {
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"Handlers\\": "/"}
  }
}
```

AuthenticateHandler.php:

```
<?php

namespace Handlers;

class AuthenticateHandler
{
    static function handle(){

    }
}
```

How i use it:

```
require_once "Handlers/vendor/autoload.php";
-----
 \Handlers\AuthenticateHandler::handle();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.` instead of `/` when referring to the current directory in autoload path. `/` actually refers to your root folder.

This should fix the issue:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Handlers\\": "."
    }
}
```